# What is “Hacke, Spitze, eins, zwei, drei”?

Tags: phrase, german-to-english, expression

I’m currently learning the German language as I’m new to Germany. Learning something new from the public every day is really cool! Yesterday I happened to hear bunch of kids playing across the street shouting:

> Hacke, Spitze, eins zwei drei.

What does it mean? Is it an expression of encouragement? Can this be used in any other situation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hacke, Spitze, Hacke, Spitze, eins, zwei, drei** is an old childrens play-verse/song that exists in plenty of varieties, sometimes also "Hacke, Spitze, hoch das Bein!" or "Ein Hut, ein Stock ein Regenschirm...vorwärts, rückwärts, seitwärts, stehn."

Core idea is that the text gives the instructions, not unlike in linedancing.

- **Hacke**
  is the heel of the foot, so it's basically tip the heel on the ground, toes up.
- **Spitze**
  is the tip, so tip with your toes.

(The numbers are just counting plain steps.)

If the children you observed were not "dancing", they were probably playing soccer, where this sequence is sometimes shouted for encouragement, here referring to different ways of playing the ball.

Comment: That's really cool. Yes! those kids were playing soccer. Thank you for the info. :)

Comment: I learned this phrase when learning Polka ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polka ).

Comment: What @Toscho said. _Hacke, Spitze, Hacke, Spitze, eins, zwei, drei, vier_. I was taught it be called _Sternpolka_, but apparantly that's wrong according to WP.

Comment: Sehr interessant. Ich habe diesen Spruch noch nie gehört. Das kann aber auch daran liegen, dass das Wort »Hacke« zumindest hier in Österreich ein Werkzeug bezeichnet, mit dem man im Garten den Boden bearbeiten kann, und dass es eine Variante davon gibt, die »Spitzhacke« (häufiger aber »Krampen«) heißt. Der Körperteil, der hier gemeint zu sein scheint, heißt in Österreich »Ferse«. In diesem Zusammenhang fällt mir ein, dass ich aber schon gehört habe, dass man die Stöckel von Stöckelschuhen offenbar auch als »Hacken« bezeichnet (etwa in »hochhackige Schuhe« = Schuhe mit hohen Stöckeln).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: In Deutschland werden Ferse und Hacke auch für den Körperteil und das Gartenwerkzeug benutzt. Nicht, dass Du das bestritten hättest, aber ein Fremdsprachler könnte leicht den falschen Schluss ziehen, dass sei exclusiv in Österreich so.

Comment: @userunknown: In Österreich ist es so, dass der hintere Teil des Fußes nicht mit dem Wort »Hacke« sondern ausschließlich mit dem Wort »Ferse« bezeichnet wird. Ist es jetzt eindeutiger, dass ich damit nichts über den Gebrauch der beiden Wörter in Deutschland aussage?

Answer (score 3):

Ja, die Zehenspitzen (Spitze), der Hacken (die Ferse).

Ich habe es beim Volkstanz gelernt, mit dem Partner:

- Hacke-Spitze, Hacke-Spitze
- dann seitwärts - 1, 2, 3, 4,
- dann zur anderen Seite: Hacke-Spitze, Hacke Spitze
- seitwärts hüpfen, 1, 2, 3, 4
- dann wird im Rhythmus geklatscht,
- man hakt sich unter, tanzt im Kreis und das Mädchen geht zum nächsten Partner.

Das war so etwa 1958-1960 (in Berlin). Jetzt lebe ich in Australien.

Answer (score 2):

I know this phrase almost exclusively in the context of football - although it's likely the origin is music/dance related. When used by a football commentator/reporter it usually refers to one team "dancing around" their opponents' defense in a - for football standards - artistic/agile fashion. Playing the ball with the tip is rather uncommon (because you have less control) and using your heel to pass the ball backwards can be considered something of a ruse to irritate the opponents. In such a context you might also hear the word *austanzen* (from *tanzen* = to dance):

> Seiler tanzt die halbe Abwehr aus!
>
> Seiler is dancing around half the opponents defense!

Meaning he is very agile and the opponents can't take the ball from him.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase is common in football (= soccer) as an expression to denote the display of fancy skills by a player. Most of the time it is meant as criticism, for instance by the coach, meaning that the player should do something simpler and more effective instead.