# What does "Spitzen" mean in the context of a kindergarten song?

Tags: vocabulary

> Hallo, hallo, schön, dass du da bist 
> Hallo, hallo, schön, dass du da bist 
> Die Hacken und die Spitzen, die wollen nicht mehr sitzen 
> Die Hacken und die Zehen, wollen weitergehen \

I tried using google translator but I don't understand the results, in english or spanish.
Looks like Hacken is heel, but I don't get it about Spitzen.

Also, why is "schön" followed by a comma? Isn't it like saying "Nice, to have you here". Like it looks weird.

I'm just starting to learn German.

Comment: There's a fun additional challenge here. If you sing this to Austrian children, they'll be confused, as _Hacke_ in Austrian German exclusively means "hatchet", never "heel" (for which only _Ferse_ is used).

Comment: And maybe this is almost a duplicate: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22334/1626.

Comment: There's the German language word *Haxe* releating to *leg*. Is this not used in Austria, also?

Comment: Absolutely, but I think _Hacke_ refers only to the same very small part of the foot as _Ferse_, doesn't it?

Comment: @phipsgabler Same in modern standard German, I'd say. I *understand* the word, but I'd never use it to mean heel, and I'm not sure I'd understand it without context. It's probably outdated or dialect, or both.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There's probably a regional difference regarding the usage of "Hacke" vs "Ferse". Here in the Ruhr area, "Hacke" is predominant, as far as I can see -- I know that it is being used here in conjunction with "Spitze" (meaning the tip of the foot) in the context of football (e.g. "Hackenschuß": kicking the ball with the heel backwards) and dancing school (e.g. for Polka, the teachers litany goes "Hacke, Spitze, Hacke, Spitze, eins und zwei und drei und vier..." when teaching the most basic steps).

Comment: If you learn to dance, there is a common thing "hacke - spitze - hacke - spitze" to discribe the moving, where one touches the ground first with the toes, the with the heel, again the toes and then the heel. I know it from some children's dance games.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

“Spitzen” here is most likely short for “Zehenspitzen” - which means the tips of (one’s) toes. The following line - which talks about heels and toes - would fit this interpretation.

And the comma isn’t related to the “schön” but rather to the “dass”, which is preceded by a comma because it connects a “Nebensatz” (subordinate clause) to the main clause of the sentence. [Here](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/nebens%C3%A4tze-dass/l-40553926/gr-40554819) is a resource that explains more in German. [Here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/WordOrder/Dependent.html) is an English one.

*Update: found a [Spanish one](https://m.dw.com/es/audio-instructor-lecci%C3%B3n-91-oraciones-subordinadas-con-que-1-nebens%C3%A4tze-mit-dass-1/av-5127863), as well!

Comment: Or just Fußspitzen.

Comment: tendiere auch eher zu *Fußspitzen* (als Gegensatz zu *Hacken*), obwohl im Kindergarten vielleicht *Zehenspitzen* insgesamt geläufiger sind.

Comment: @CarstenS Could be if you regard *Fußspitzen* and *Zehen* as synonyms (see lines 3 and 4). But I doubt that kindergarten-children make a difference between *Zehen* and *Zehenspitzen* although there is one.